# Writing Avro with Dynamic Schema in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, avro, file-writing, apache-beam-io, dynamic-schema

I need to write GenericRecords into several Avro files with different Schemas.

What are the possible approaches besides AvroIO.writeCustomTypeToGenericRecords() with custom class that expands DynamicAvroDestinations? I followed more or less the same procedure from [*"Writing data to multiple destinations" paragraph*](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html#writeCustomTypeToGenericRecords--) but the documentation says that the [.to(DynamicAvroDestinations<UserT,NewDestinationT,OutputT> dynamicDestinations)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.TypedWrite.html) method is already deprecated suggesting to use FileIO.write() or FileIO.writeDynamic() without any further documentation or code examples.

Comment: Let me clarify - you have an input PCollection and you want to output its records into the different Avro files  with different schemas? If yes, I expect that you know how determine which schema to use for the current record, right?

Comment: Yes, technically you can extract it from the GenericRecord itself by calling the getSchema() method. However all the non-AVRO dynamic destination classes expect it to be accessed through the manipulation of the destination string, which could be used, for example, as a key for a sideInput Map or something similar. I haven't found any good code examples for now that use FileIO.writeDynamic() or similar, but fortunately DynamicAvroDestinations still works, even though it is deprecated.

Comment: Did you consider to branch out your input PCollection depending on a current schema of element and write every "branched" PCollection with a proper AvroIO.write() instance ?

Comment: It could be a possibility. However, even though I might be able to branch my PCollection according to the schema, I would still need to pass it somehow as an argument to the write method. How would that be possible?

Comment: If you already know the schemas then you can pass them to every AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(Schema) instance created in every branch, don't you?

Comment: not exactly because I have the access to the schema either from the generic record itself or I should access it through i sideInput map both of which are inside the pipeline and hinders me from passing an argument explicitly.